# Customizing material-slider in AngularDart

Tags: angular-material, angular-dart

I want to customize the `<material-slider>` component in AngularDart. I want to add a marker to a certain value like so:

`------|----O-------`

The `|` here is the marker that I would like to add and the `O` here is the normal knob of the slider. There won't be any user interaction with the marker, I'll just set it from code.

What's the best way of doing this? Should I reach its DOM and inject something there? Can I extend the `MaterialSlider` class? Are there any examples that may be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up displaying the marker behind the `material-slider`. This way I didn't have to modify the `material-slider` at all.

I created a parent `div` with `position: relative` which has the `material-slider` and the marker `div` as children. The marker `div` has `position: absolute` and `left: 50%` to place it right in the middle of the slider.

Other things I explored were:

- Yes it seems you can extend components, no it's not fun.
- You can get the `dart:html` `Element` of your own component that has the `material-slider` and add stuff into it. For this, you inject `Element` to your constructor. However, you have to use it in `AfterViewInit` to have the `material-slider` be created as a child. `querySelector()` helps you get to the `Element` of `material-slider`, after which you can do things like `slider.children.add()`

Comment: I'd say this is the best solution for this. Using composition allows you to mostly decouple from the implementation of slider. Extending is mostly an anti-pattern, except for very specific cases mostly internal to angular_component.